# Detectron2 object detection

Tags: python, pytorch, detectron

Do anyone know what is this error:
`WARNING:root:Torch AMP is not available on this platform`

Because I followed this detectron2 object detection tutorial: https://github.com/AarohiSingla/Detectron2-Tutorial/blob/main/Detectron_maskrcnn_custom_dataset_baloon.ipynb

and when I do this (to visualize annotations):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
dataset_dicts = get_balloon_dicts("balloon_dataset/balloon/train")
for d in random.sample(dataset_dicts, 3):
    img = cv2.imread(d["file_name"])
    visualizer = Visualizer(img[:, :, ::-1], metadata=balloon_metadata, scale=0.5)
    out = visualizer.draw_dataset_dict(d)
    cv2_imshow(out.get_image()[:, :, ::-1])
```

or this (to visualize output):

```
from detectron2.utils.visualizer import ColorMode
dataset_dicts = get_balloon_dicts("balloon_dataset/balloon/val")
for d in random.sample(dataset_dicts, 1):    
    im = cv2.imread(d["file_name"])
    outputs = predictor(im)  # format is documented at https://detectron2.readthedocs.io/tutorials/models.html#model-output-format
    v = Visualizer(im[:, :, ::-1],
                   metadata=balloon_metadata, 
                   scale=0.5, 
                   instance_mode=ColorMode.IMAGE_BW   # remove the colors of unsegmented pixels. This option is only available for segmentation models
    )
    out = v.draw_instance_predictions(outputs["instances"].to("cpu"))
    cv2_imshow(out.get_image()[:, :, ::-1])
```

the error shows me and after error I got:

```
`[11/02 12:52:02 d2.checkpoint.c2_model_loading]: Following weights matched with model:`
| Names in Model                                  | Names in Checkpoint                                                                                  | Shapes                                          |
|:------------------------------------------------|:-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|:------------------------------------------------|
| backbone.bottom_up.res2.0.conv1.*               | backbone.bottom_up.res2.0.conv1.{norm.bias,norm.running_mean,norm.running_var,norm.weight,weight}    | (64,) (64,) (64,) (64,) (64,64,1,1)             |
| backbone.bottom_up.res2.0.conv2.*               | backbone.bottom_up.res2.0.conv2.{norm.bias,norm.running_mean,norm.running_var,norm.weight,weight}    | (64,) (64,) (64,) (64,) (64,64,3,3)             |
| backbone.bottom_up.res2.0.conv3.*               | backbone.bottom_up.res2.0.conv3.{norm.bias,norm.running_mean,norm.running_var,norm.weight,weight}    | (256,) (256,) (256,) (256,) (256,64,1,1)        |
| backbone.bottom_up.res2.0.shortcut.*            | backbone.bottom_up.res2.0.shortcut.{norm.bias,norm.running_mean,norm.running_var,norm.weight,weight} | (256,) (256,) (256,) (256,) (256,64,1,1)        |
| backbone.bottom_up.res2.1.conv1.*               | backbone.bottom_up.res2.1.conv1.{norm.bias,norm.running_mean,norm.running_var,norm.weight,weight}    | (64,) (64,) (64,) (64,) (64,256,1,1)            |
| backbone.bottom_up.res2.1.conv2.*               | backbone.bottom_up.res2.1.conv2.{norm.bias,norm.running_mean,norm.running_var,norm.weight,weight}    | (64,) (64,) (64,) (64,) (64,64,3,3)             |
| backbone.bottom_up.res2.1.conv3.*               | backbone.bottom_up.res2.1.conv3.{norm.bias,norm.running_mean,norm.running_var,norm.weight,weight}    | (256,) (256,) (256,) (256,) (256,64,1,1)        |
| backbone.bottom_up.res2.2.conv1.*               | backbone.bottom_up.res2.2.conv1.{norm.bias,norm.running_mean,norm.running_var,norm.weight,weight}    | (64,) (64,) (64,) (64,) (64,256,1,1)            |
| backbone.bottom_up.res2.2.conv2.*               | backbone.bottom_up.res2.2.conv2.{norm.bias,norm.running_mean,norm.running_var,norm.weight,weight}    | (64,) (64,) (64,) (64,) (64,64,3,3)             |
| backbone.bottom_up.res2.2.conv3.*               | backbone.bottom_up.res2.2.conv3.{norm.bias,norm.running_mean,norm.running_var,norm.weight,weight}    | (256,) (256,) (256,) (256,) (256,64,1,1)        |
| backbone.bottom_up.res3.0.conv1.*               | backbone.bottom_up.res3.0.conv1.{norm.bias,norm.running_mean,norm.running_var,norm.weight,weight}    | (128,) (128,) (128,) (128,) (128,256,1,1)       |
| backbone.bottom_up.res3.0.conv2.*               | backbone.bottom_up.res3.0.conv2.{norm.bias,norm.running_mean,norm.running_var,norm.weight,weight}    | (128,) (128,) (128,) (128,) (128,128,3,3)       |
| backbone.bottom_up.res3.0.conv3.*               | backbone.bottom_up.res3.0.conv3.{norm.bias,norm.running_mean,norm.running_var,norm.weight,weight}    | (512,) (512,) (512,) (512,) (512,128,1,1)       |
| backbone.bottom_up.res3.0.shortcut.*            | backbone.bottom_up.res3.0.shortcut.{norm.bias,norm.running_mean,norm.running_var,norm.weight,weight} | (512,) (512,) (512,) (512,) (512,256,1,1)       |
| backbone.bottom_up.res3.1.conv1.*               | backbone.bottom_up.res3.1.conv1.{norm.bias,norm.running_mean,norm.running_var,norm.weight,weight}    | (128,) (128,) (128,) (128,) (128,512,1,1)       |
| backbone.bottom_up.res3.1.conv2.*               | backbone.bottom_up.res3.1.conv2.{norm.bias,norm.running_mean,norm.running_var,norm.weight,weight}    | (128,) (128,) (128,) (128,) (128,128,3,3)       |
| backbone.bottom_up.res3.1.conv3.*               | backbone.bottom_up.res3.1.conv3.{norm.bias,norm.running_mean,norm.running_var,norm.weight,weight}    | (512,) (512,) (512,) (512,) (512,128,1,1)       |
| backbone.bottom_up.res3.2.conv1.*               | backbone.bottom_up.res3.2.conv1.{norm.bias,norm.running_mean,norm.running_var,norm.weight,weight}    | (128,) (128,) (128,) (128,) (128,512,1,1)       |
| backbone.bottom_up.res3.2.conv2.*               | backbone.bottom_up.res3.2.conv2.{norm.bias,norm.running_mean,norm.running_var,norm.weight,weight}    | (128,) (128,) (128,) (128,) (128,128,3,3)       |
| backbone.bottom_up.res3.2.conv3.*               | backbone.bottom_up.res3.2.conv3.{norm.bias,norm.running_mean,norm.running_var,norm.weight,weight}    | (512,) (512,) (512,) (512,) (512,128,1,1)       |
| backbone.bottom_up.res3.3.conv1.*               | backbone.bottom_up.res3.3.conv1.{norm.bias,norm.running_mean,norm.running_var,norm.weight,weight}    | (128,) (128,) (128,) (128,) (128,512,1,1)       |
| backbone.bottom_up.res3.3.conv2.*               | backbone.bottom_up.res3.3.conv2.{norm.bias,norm.running_mean,norm.running_var,norm.weight,weight}    | (128,) (128,) (128,) (128,) (128,128,3,3)       |
| backbone.bottom_up.res3.3.conv3.*               | backbone.bottom_up.res3.3.conv3.{norm.bias,norm.running_mean,norm.running_var,norm.weight,weight}    | (512,) (512,) (512,) (512,) (512,128,1,1)       |
| backbone.bottom_up.res4.0.conv1.*               | backbone.bottom_up.res4.0.conv1.{norm.bias,norm.running_mean,norm.running_var,norm.weight,weight}    | (256,) (256,) (256,) (256,) (256,512,1,1)       |
| backbone.bottom_up.res4.0.conv2.*               | backbone.bottom_up.res4.0.conv2.{norm.bias,norm.running_mean,norm.running_var,norm.weight,weight}    | (256,) (256,) (256,) (256,) (256,256,3,3)       |
| backbone.bottom_up.res4.0.conv3.*               | backbone.bottom_up.res4.0.conv3.{norm.bias,norm.running_mean,norm.running_var,norm.weight,weight}    | (1024,) (1024,) (1024,) (1024,) (1024,256,1,1)  |
| backbone.bottom_up.res4.0.shortcut.*            | backbone.bottom_up.res4.0.shortcut.{norm.bias,norm.running_mean,norm.running_var,norm.weight,weight} | (1024,) (1024,) (1024,) (1024,) (1024,512,1,1)  |
| backbone.bottom_up.res4.1.conv1.*               | backbone.bottom_up.res4.1.conv1.{norm.bias,norm.running_mean,norm.running_var,norm.weight,weight}    | (256,) (256,) (256,) (256,) (256,1024,1,1)      |
| backbone.bottom_up.res4.1.conv2.*               | backbone.bottom_up.res4.1.conv2.{norm.bias,norm.running_mean,norm.running_var,norm.weight,weight}    | (256,) (256,) (256,) (256,) (256,256,3,3)       |
| backbone.bottom_up.res4.1.conv3.*               | backbone.bottom_up.res4.1.conv3.{norm.bias,norm.running_mean,norm.running_var,norm.weight,weight}    | (1024,) (1024,) (1024,) (1024,) (1024,256,1,1)  |
| backbone.bottom_up.res4.2.conv1.*               | backbone.bottom_up.res4.2.conv1.{norm.bias,norm.running_mean,norm.running_var,norm.weight,weight}    | (256,) (256,) (256,) (256,) (256,1024,1,1)      |
| backbone.bottom_up.res4.2.conv2.*               | backbone.bottom_up.res4.2.conv2.{norm.bias,norm.running_mean,norm.running_var,norm.weight,weight}    | (256,) (256,) (256,) (256,) (256,256,3,3)       |
| backbone.bottom_up.res4.2.conv3.*               | backbone.bottom_up.res4.2.conv3.{norm.bias,norm.running_mean,norm.running_var,norm.weight,weight}    | (1024,) (1024,) (1024,) (1024,) (1024,256,1,1)  |
| backbone.bottom_up.res4.3.conv1.*               | backbone.bottom_up.res4.3.conv1.{norm.bias,norm.running_mean,norm.running_var,norm.weight,weight}    | (256,) (256,) (256,) (256,) (256,1024,1,1)      |
| backbone.bottom_up.res4.3.conv2.*               | backbone.bottom_up.res4.3.conv2.{norm.bias,norm.running_mean,norm.running_var,norm.weight,weight}    | (256,) (256,) (256,) (256,) (256,256,3,3)       |
| backbone.bottom_up.res4.3.conv3.*               | backbone.bottom_up.res4.3.conv3.{norm.bias,norm.running_mean,norm.running_var,norm.weight,weight}    | (1024,) (1024,) (1024,) (1024,) (1024,256,1,1)  |
| backbone.bottom_up.res4.4.conv1.*               | backbone.bottom_up.res4.4.conv1.{norm.bias,norm.running_mean,norm.running_var,norm.weight,weight}    | (256,) (256,) (256,) (256,) (256,1024,1,1)      |
| backbone.bottom_up.res4.4.conv2.*               | backbone.bottom_up.res4.4.conv2.{norm.bias,norm.running_mean,norm.running_var,norm.weight,weight}    | (256,) (256,) (256,) (256,) (256,256,3,3)       |
| backbone.bottom_up.res4.4.conv3.*               | backbone.bottom_up.res4.4.conv3.{norm.bias,norm.running_mean,norm.running_var,norm.weight,weight}    | (1024,) (1024,) (1024,) (1024,) (1024,256,1,1)  |
| backbone.bottom_up.res4.5.conv1.*               | backbone.bottom_up.res4.5.conv1.{norm.bias,norm.running_mean,norm.running_var,norm.weight,weight}    | (256,) (256,) (256,) (256,) (256,1024,1,1)      |
| backbone.bottom_up.res4.5.conv2.*               | backbone.bottom_up.res4.5.conv2.{norm.bias,norm.running_mean,norm.running_var,norm.weight,weight}    | (256,) (256,) (256,) (256,) (256,256,3,3)       |
| backbone.bottom_up.res4.5.conv3.*               | backbone.bottom_up.res4.5.conv3.{norm.bias,norm.running_mean,norm.running_var,norm.weight,weight}    | (1024,) (1024,) (1024,) (1024,) (1024,256,1,1)  |
| backbone.bottom_up.res5.0.conv1.*               | backbone.bottom_up.res5.0.conv1.{norm.bias,norm.running_mean,norm.running_var,norm.weight,weight}    | (512,) (512,) (512,) (512,) (512,1024,1,1)      |
| backbone.bottom_up.res5.0.conv2.*               | backbone.bottom_up.res5.0.conv2.{norm.bias,norm.running_mean,norm.running_var,norm.weight,weight}    | (512,) (512,) (512,) (512,) (512,512,3,3)       |
| backbone.bottom_up.res5.0.conv3.*               | backbone.bottom_up.res5.0.conv3.{norm.bias,norm.running_mean,norm.running_var,norm.weight,weight}    | (2048,) (2048,) (2048,) (2048,) (2048,512,1,1)  |
| backbone.bottom_up.res5.0.shortcut.*            | backbone.bottom_up.res5.0.shortcut.{norm.bias,norm.running_mean,norm.running_var,norm.weight,weight} | (2048,) (2048,) (2048,) (2048,) (2048,1024,1,1) |
| backbone.bottom_up.res5.1.conv1.*               | backbone.bottom_up.res5.1.conv1.{norm.bias,norm.running_mean,norm.running_var,norm.weight,weight}    | (512,) (512,) (512,) (512,) (512,2048,1,1)      |
| backbone.bottom_up.res5.1.conv2.*               | backbone.bottom_up.res5.1.conv2.{norm.bias,norm.running_mean,norm.running_var,norm.weight,weight}    | (512,) (512,) (512,) (512,) (512,512,3,3)       |
| backbone.bottom_up.res5.1.conv3.*               | backbone.bottom_up.res5.1.conv3.{norm.bias,norm.running_mean,norm.running_var,norm.weight,weight}    | (2048,) (2048,) (2048,) (2048,) (2048,512,1,1)  |
| backbone.bottom_up.res5.2.conv1.*               | backbone.bottom_up.res5.2.conv1.{norm.bias,norm.running_mean,norm.running_var,norm.weight,weight}    | (512,) (512,) (512,) (512,) (512,2048,1,1)      |
| backbone.bottom_up.res5.2.conv2.*               | backbone.bottom_up.res5.2.conv2.{norm.bias,norm.running_mean,norm.running_var,norm.weight,weight}    | (512,) (512,) (512,) (512,) (512,512,3,3)       |
| backbone.bottom_up.res5.2.conv3.*               | backbone.bottom_up.res5.2.conv3.{norm.bias,norm.running_mean,norm.running_var,norm.weight,weight}    | (2048,) (2048,) (2048,) (2048,) (2048,512,1,1)  |
| backbone.bottom_up.stem.conv1.*                 | backbone.bottom_up.stem.conv1.{norm.bias,norm.running_mean,norm.running_var,norm.weight,weight}      | (64,) (64,) (64,) (64,) (64,3,7,7)              |
| backbone.fpn_lateral2.*                         | backbone.fpn_lateral2.{bias,weight}                                                                  | (256,) (256,256,1,1)                            |
| backbone.fpn_lateral3.*                         | backbone.fpn_lateral3.{bias,weight}                                                                  | (256,) (256,512,1,1)                            |
| backbone.fpn_lateral4.*                         | backbone.fpn_lateral4.{bias,weight}                                                                  | (256,) (256,1024,1,1)                           |
| backbone.fpn_lateral5.*                         | backbone.fpn_lateral5.{bias,weight}                                                                  | (256,) (256,2048,1,1)                           |
| backbone.fpn_output2.*                          | backbone.fpn_output2.{bias,weight}                                                                   | (256,) (256,256,3,3)                            |
| backbone.fpn_output3.*                          | backbone.fpn_output3.{bias,weight}                                                                   | (256,) (256,256,3,3)                            |
| backbone.fpn_output4.*                          | backbone.fpn_output4.{bias,weight}                                                                   | (256,) (256,256,3,3)                            |
| backbone.fpn_output5.*                          | backbone.fpn_output5.{bias,weight}                                                                   | (256,) (256,256,3,3)                            |
| proposal_generator.rpn_head.anchor_deltas.*     | proposal_generator.rpn_head.anchor_deltas.{bias,weight}                                              | (12,) (12,256,1,1)                              |
| proposal_generator.rpn_head.conv.*              | proposal_generator.rpn_head.conv.{bias,weight}                                                       | (256,) (256,256,3,3)                            |
| proposal_generator.rpn_head.objectness_logits.* | proposal_generator.rpn_head.objectness_logits.{bias,weight}                                          | (3,) (3,256,1,1)                                |
| roi_heads.box_head.fc1.*                        | roi_heads.box_head.fc1.{bias,weight}                                                                 | (1024,) (1024,12544)                            |
| roi_heads.box_head.fc2.*                        | roi_heads.box_head.fc2.{bias,weight}                                                                 | (1024,) (1024,1024)                             |
| roi_heads.box_predictor.bbox_pred.*             | roi_heads.box_predictor.bbox_pred.{bias,weight}                                                      | (4,) (4,1024)                                   |
| roi_heads.box_predictor.cls_score.*             | roi_heads.box_predictor.cls_score.{bias,weight}                                                      | (2,) (2,1024)                                   |
| roi_heads.mask_head.deconv.*                    | roi_heads.mask_head.deconv.{bias,weight}                                                             | (256,) (256,256,2,2)                            |
| roi_heads.mask_head.mask_fcn1.*                 | roi_heads.mask_head.mask_fcn1.{bias,weight}                                                          | (256,) (256,256,3,3)                            |
| roi_heads.mask_head.mask_fcn2.*                 | roi_heads.mask_head.mask_fcn2.{bias,weight}                                                          | (256,) (256,256,3,3)                            |
| roi_heads.mask_head.mask_fcn3.*                 | roi_heads.mask_head.mask_fcn3.{bias,weight}                                                          | (256,) (256,256,3,3)                            |
| roi_heads.mask_head.mask_fcn4.*                 | roi_heads.mask_head.mask_fcn4.{bias,weight}                                                          | (256,) (256,256,3,3)                            |
| roi_heads.mask_head.predictor.*                 | roi_heads.mask_head.predictor.{bias,weight}                                                          | (1,) (1,256,1,1)                                |
```

I just wanna to visualize my output.

Answer (score 0):

To check if Torch AMP is available on your platform, you can run the following command:

```
import torch
torch.cuda.is_available()
```